# Consequences of the negation of the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

There are many sources documenting the consequences of the Riemann hypothesis, but I can't find one discussing the consequences of its negation, particularly concerning the prime distribution.

Can anyone refer some literature regarding this topic?

Comment: many many papers will be worthless.

Comment: Also discussed [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/136414/what-if-the-riemann-hypothesis-were-false).

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#cite_ref-Rib320_31-0) reads: _$\varphi(n)<\frac n{e^\gamma\log\log n}$ for infinitely many $n$. Ribenboim says "The method of proof is interesting, in that the inequality is shown first under the assumption that the Riemann hypothesis is true, secondly under the contrary assumption."_ [$^{[31]}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#cite_note-Rib320-31)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there are not too many articles discussing the consequences of the failure of RH. More often one can read that the failure would be a "disaster". Concerning the prime distribution, 
Enrico Bombieri puts it as follows: “The failure of the Riemann Hypothesis would create havoc in the distribution of prime numbers”.

If the Riemann hypothesis were false then also
$$
\pi(x)=\int_2^x \frac{dt}{\log(t)}+O(\sqrt{x}\log(x))
$$
were false, i.e., the error term would be worse. 
In this case the question would be how good (how large) the
zero-free regions of $\zeta(s)$ really are.
Certainly the prime distribution then would have a very interesting behaviour. 
On the other hand, De la Vallee-Poussin already constructed in 1896 a good zero-free region for $\zeta(s)$ (good enough to prove PNT at least)  yielding an error term $O(xe^{-c\log(x)})$.